# Can a decompiler deduce the strings I wrote in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I found this decompiler:
https://ethervm.io/decompile
and my code is :

```
function compareMyStrings(string memory a) public view returns (bool) {
    return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == 'mySecretCodeString');
}
```

'mySecretCodeString',
Can this string be cracked?
Thank you very much!

Comment: This looks very close to how servers validate password hashes; you'd just compare `keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a)))` to the result of `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(("mySecretCodeString")))`, computed beforehand by you. E.g., if the result was `856c0bf2d9e8800cfb5e9819a262a663` (it's not), you'd do `keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == '856c0bf2d9e8800cfb5e9819a262a663'` and it should properly validate the password. Just keep in mind that Keccak-256 isn't a password hash, so it's very fast to compute, so your password should be very long if you hope to achieve any real security with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be cracked.

By the way, remember that at the moment that you send the correct secret word to the contract, to the `compareMyStrings` function, it will be visible by everybody while the transaction is sitting in the mempool. So, this is not secure at all.

Also, you are comparing the result of `keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a)))` which is a hash of 32 bytes, with the literal string `"mySecretCodeString"`. That will never be true.

Maybe you meant:

```js
contract Contract {
    function compareMyStrings(string memory a) public pure returns (bool) {
        return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(("mySecretCodeString"))));
    }
}
```

This works. But it's a bad idea anyways.

Converting your "mySecretCodeString" to bytes, it shows: 6d79536563726574436f6465537472696e67

Try it yourself here: https://onlinestringtools.com/convert-string-to-bytes

[image]

If we search `6d79536563726574436f6465537472696e67` in your decompiled contract (I deployed the contract with your function and decompiled it here: https://ethervm.io/decompile/rinkeby/0x951874e72fa988119e21a19b2ab745baf9189d1d):

It shows:

[image]

So, the hardcoded string "mySecretCodeString" is still in your contract, just encoded in bytes.

Converting those bytes to string using https://onlinestringtools.com/convert-bytes-to-string, we see:

[image]